# Read JSON formatted string in Python

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x

I have a simple Websockets server in python, it receives messages from Android app clients, I tried to make the message payload from the client in JSON but I felt. It is only working when it is in String.
One solution I found is to keep the message string but with JSON format:

```js
try {
    json.put("name", "Jack");
    json.put("age", "24");
    message = json.toString(2);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

webSocket.send(message);
```

Inspired by the Javascript `JSON.stringify(message)`

I printed the message on the server and it seems to be formatted

[image]

My question is how can I reverse back it into JSON on the server when it received?

I tried this way in Python:

```
def on_message(self,message):
    data = json.loads(message)
    self.write_message(data['name'])
```

but I got this error:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception in /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 494, in _run_callback
    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 24, in on_message
    data = json.loads(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The [``json``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) documentation shows examples to encode and decode json, i.e. going from json to string and vice versa

Comment: Printing the value of `message` given to `json.loads()` will be very helpful.

Comment: You should really try to print it from within the function. It seems you are calling it with an empty string value for `message`.
For example, `json.loads('')` gives a very similar error in my installation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `json` Python package. To have a JSON, you could simply do `import json` and `json.dumps(message)`.

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this work for you?

```
import json

# assume this is the JSON you receive
text = json.dumps(dict(name='Jack', age='24'))

# show the text to be converted
print(text)
# outputs: {"name": "Jack", "age": "24"}

# load a string and convert to Python object
# see `json` module more for details
obj = json.loads(text)
```

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, I updated the question with the error.

Comment: can you print the value of `message`?

Comment: I could, and It gives me the message formatted as I send it. But I don't know how to re-parse it again into JSON

Comment: if you could show, it may be easier to spot the issue. Maybe it is some custom formatting or whitespace or something silly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Json package in python

```
import json
data = json.loads(your_var)
```

In data variable you get a json format data

hope this will help you

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it worked for me, I converted the message into a dictionary using `ast` and then used the new message as I wanted:

```
    formattedMessage = ast.literal_eval(format(message))
    self.write_message(formattedMessage["name"])
```

Comment: If the source is a `json` text, this is going to produce very fragile code. I would rather make sure that a proper JSON parser works. `simplejson` is known to produce more informative error messages, if that helps you.